# yii2 Db column return Incorrect JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, yii2, yii2-model

One of my columns in my db( levels table ) has JSON type.

When I write some query like this

```
   1)  $levels = Levels::find()
              ->select("level_permissions")
              ->column();

   2) $levels = Levels::find()
              ->select("level_permissions")
              ->all();
```

In second(2) version I will get my json string in " quotes" 
  For example

```
"{\"name\":\"level_name\",\"active\":\"1\",\"level_administering_level_id\":\"1\"},\"LevelAccessPermission\":{\"31\":\"1\"}"
```

But in first(1) I have bug
  it returns

```
""{\"name\":\"level_name\",\"active\":\"1\",\"level_administering_level_id\":\"1\"},\"LevelAccessPermission\":{\"31\":\"1\"} ""
```

and when I decode it I get

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(584) "{"lev_name":"ssssssssss","lev_active":"1","lev_administering_level_id":"1"},"LevelAccessPermission":{"31":"1"}}"
```

The problem is in quotes. in second version the string is in quotes, but when I use -> column(), I have some "" empty double quotes, then my json, then empty double quotes.

Why in column case ? I get double quotes before and after json. I have it only when I use yii2 -> column().

Any advice... Do you have some bug like this? Any idea?

Comment: its hard to guess with this example data what could be the problem try adding the actual code and column in the code rather than generic example as the mistake could be anywhere may be you are overlooking and someone else can find it .

Comment: I change it ... it's real example , part of my code...

Comment: Which version of Yii you're using?

Comment: i use  yii2 advanced